# *Addition is commutative in ring without identity* can be deduced from other axioms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The beginner of Ring Theory may have came across following question:

> Let $(R,+,\cdot)$ be a ring (may be non-commutative) with unity. Show that the condition (axiom) *$a+b=b+a$ for all $a,b$* in defition of ring can be deduced from other axioms of ring.

Just expand $(1+1).(a+b)$ in two ways to deduce above axiom.

I was considering *if this is still valid for ring  $R$ without unity*; is this true?

**Q.** If $(R,+,\cdot)$ is a ring without unity, can we deduce axiom $a+b=b+a$ ($a,b\in R$)from other axioms in definition of ring?

Comment: Not sure about the definitions right now, but:
Is every abelian group $(G, +, 0)$ with trivial multiplication (i.e. $ab = 0$ for all $a,b \in G$) a commutative ring without identity? If yes, the case for $G$ not abelian should do it?

Comment: @PaulK Seems that we were thinking the same thing at the same time.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/609364/why-is-ring-addition-commutative (the most upvoted answer mentions this construction).

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1336199/smallest-two-sided-nearring.  There are nontrivial examples there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take any non-Abelian group $G$ and call its operation addition and its identity 0.  Define multiplication by $\forall a, b \in G: ab = 0$.  This satisfies the axioms of a ring without identity except for the commutativity of addition.

Comment: I went on to try to think of more interesting examples but the links provided by the others have done that job well.  It is worth remembering this trivial multiplication as a test case for hypotheses.