# Types of rings satisfying certain properties

Tags: ring-theory

I was just wondering if there are rings that satisfy exactly five, but not all of the six ring axioms and a finite ring other than the trivial ring {0}. Just to make sure we’re on the same page, the axioms are described below:
Let $R$ be a ring. Then $R$ satisfies the following:

1) Commutativity of addition: $\forall a,b\in R, a+b \in R \Leftrightarrow b+a\in R$.

2) Associativity of addition

3) Associativity of multiplication

4) Distributive property

5) Additive Identity ($\forall a\in R, \exists “0”\in R (a+0)= a$).

6) Additive Inverse ($\forall a\in R, \exists “-a”\in R (a+(-a) = 0$)

Note: the additive identity and additive inverse do **not** have to be $0$ and $-a$ respectively.

If we define addition and multiplication in the integers by the usual operations, then the set of integers is a ring.

I feel like it’s easy to find rings that don’t satisfy the distributive property:

If we define addition and multiplication as $ab$ and $a+b$, then the ring satisfies all the axioms except for distributivity.

As for a finite ring, I know that the integers $modulo\space n$, where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, is a finite, unital ring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If we define addition and multiplication as  and +, then the ring satisfies all the axioms except for distributivity.

Good try, but not quite. If addition is defined as $a\dotplus b=ab$ where the thing on the right is the old product in a ring, then it won't be possible to have an $\dotplus$ inverse for $0$. The problem is that $0$ is absorbing with respect to $\dotplus$ (that is, $0\dotplus b=0$ for all $b$, so $f(b)=0\dotplus b$ is not 1-1) but in any abelian group the function $f(b)=e+b$ is 1-1, because of the existence of inverses.  So it does *not* satisfy as many axioms as you thought.

### Examples

If you take a nontrivial finite abelian group $G$, the set of functions $G\to G$ satisfies all requirements except 4), because it doesn't distribute on one side. (I'm pretty sure *nontrivial* abelian suffices, but maybe there are some edge cases.) This is an example of a **near-ring**.

If you just take the nonnegative integers $\mathbb N$ with regular addition and multiplication, you get something that is only missing 6). This is an example of a **semi-ring**.

You can't have 6) without 5) because 6) is defined in terms of 5), so that one is not possible.

The cross product on $\mathbb R^3$, along with standard vector addition, provides an example of a **nonassociative algebra**, one which is only missing 3).

It seems you can demonstrate there is [a near-ring that is distributive on both sides](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/693969/29335), which has a nonabelian group underlying the $+$ operation.  That satisfies everything except 1).

I am not immediately sure about an example only lacking 2)... I'd have to get back to you on that one.  I found [this earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3032585/29335) which seems to be asking for confirmation they found such an example, but I have not proofread it.

Comment: Also, just an unrelated, simple other question: An additive inverse or identity of an element $a$ in a ring $R$ does **not** need to be “-a” or “0” respectively. But then, wouldn’t the set of $(\mathbb{N}\bigcup \{0\})$ modulo $3$ be such a ring?

Comment: Q1: I'm pretty sure you can find an example of this for yourself if you just select a small abelian group and try its set of functions.  Q2: presumably you meant distributivity holds on both sides when you said 4.  Q3: yes.  Q4: the only cross product on $\mathbb R^2$ that I know is not a binary operation... so I don't understand your question.

Comment: @rschweib, oh yeah, I forgot that cross products only occur on $\mathbb{R}^3$ so please ignore that stupid question. 
Also, you still **haven’t answered** my question of whether the additive inverse has to be “-a” and the additive identity has to be “0”. Also, do you have **any tips** as to how you **came up** with such examples and how to come up with **such** rings in the first place? I know there probably isn’t a general formula for finding **such rings**, but I often find that difficult to do. Is it true that an **in-depth** understanding of the material can help in finding them?

Comment: @rschweib, do you have any tips as to how you’ve managed to understand ring theory to such depth? Like, have you read a lot of ring theory books and understood them? Do you rewrite proofs you don’t understand the first time? Do you write proofs for similar problems?

Comment: Sorry for spelling your nickname wrong @rschwieb

Comment: could you provide an example of a set of functions of an abelian group that does not satisfy 4)?

Comment: Also, **the integers modulo 3** is an example of a finite unital ring, right?

Comment: @fordjones I’m pretty sure everybody learns math by reading, listening, and doing problems, yes.